# AWS .NET SDK: cannot access S3 from S3 endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, endpoint

my web servers needs to access S3. When I place them in the public subnets, or place them in the private subnets and use NAT gateways, everything works fine:

```
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client("myaccesskey", "mysecretkey", enRegion);
PutObjectRequest putReq = new PutObjectRequest();
putReq.FilePath = "c:\temp\myphoto.jpg";
putReq.BucketName = "MyBucket";
putReq.Key = "myphoto.jpg";
PutObjectResponse putResp = client.PutObject(putReq);
```

Now I tried to place the web servers in the private subnet with S3 endpoints, my code can no longer access S3. Do I need to change the code?

Comment: Have you configured the Route Table to use the S3 VPC Endpoint? Are you trying to access a bucket in the same region as your VPC, or in a different region? What error message are you receiving? (Feel free to Edit your question to add details.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a FYI VPC's are truly private. Only traffic that you explicitly allow can transit the borders of the VPC.

So, inside a VPC, instances needing access to external resources either need to be assigned an EIP (in which case they can access external resources using AWS's infrastructure), or you need to provide a NAT host (in which case all of the traffic egresses the VPC via your own NAT).

**As of May 11th, 2015, AWS has released a "VPC Endpoint" for S3, which allows access to S3 directly from a VPC without having to go through a proxy host or NAT instance**

You Can Create Endpoint, choose the desired VPC, and customize the access policy (if you want):

Please Refer [AWS Blog Post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/) For Details.

Hope this helps.